# how to export data to computer(PC) using wifi or http connection?

Tags: iphone, network-programming, bluetooth

I have made Iphone applicatio. In my application whatever data i have recorded; all that data i want to export to the Computer using the application.

Is there any way available to sent data to computer using wifi using developed application? Can we use Bluetooth or Http connection to send application from device to the PC?

if we can than how can we manage the bluetooth and how to use it without Jailbreaking?

if any body has any solution,please give any code or any link or any other solution which would appreciated.

Thanks, 
Mishal

Comment: Please search this site, before posting another duplicate.  There have been many similar questions like this, in the past few days.  Including the three that were yours, which were responded to.

Comment: OK; intervention... I've merged 3 of these duplicates and deleted another. **DO NOT KEEP ASKING THE SAME QUESTION**. Either improve this question (edit) with anything that is missing, or ask a *different* question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to send the data using HTTP or FTP to a server, which could be your PC.  Would that work for you?

[Here's one way to do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936855/file-upload-to-http-server-in-iphone-programming/937475#937475)

[Here's another.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408759/how-can-we-do-background-file-upload-in-iphone/1409745#1409745)

[And one for FTP.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266176/upload-file-to-ftp-server-on-iphone/1272889#1272889)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you have an option to gain control of a computer and toss a file in there from within an iPhone app.  You cannot do it over the usb cord, you cannot mount the drive unless you roll your own fs mounter (pretty difficult), and you cannot push a file over html or something and have it magically appear.  The user would have to interact at some point.

Many times, this is done over html. In my apps, I use [CocoaHTTPServer](http://code.google.com/p/cocoahttpserver/) to get local info into and off of the phone. You run the server and out-of-the-box, it indexes all the files in the documents directory for you to download from any browser on the same wifi network. Give it a shot as it is a easy to implement solution for getting large files off the phone without having to resort to something clunky like email

Comment: you *know* that this question has been asked the same way 3 times by the same user; please don't give the same reply each time. Duplicates should be closed.