# C# Solution to upload a file

Tags: asp.net, iphone, cocoa-touch, upload

Can someone provide me with a way of uploading files, such as images or text files,from an  iphone app to a web server. I have found many examples but all are in php. I'm using C# with ASP.NET and need to do a simple upload. Thanks in advance.

I actually needed a solution for the iphone app. How to upload the file from the iphone to an asp.net website. I already have the upload and where it is to be stored, I just need assistance as far as the class to use on the iphone and how to incorporate that with the website.

Comment: Well, if you were looking for an iPhone app solution (thus, not c# code), you should really change your question's title and tags. I will retag it with Cocoa right now, because that's what you specified in your answer.

Comment: @Chris, @Maxim Z; one word: monotouch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125306/how-can-i-upload-a-photo-to-a-server-with-the-iphone). It Worked for me. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

[How to upload a file to a Web server in ASP.NET by using Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323246/EN-US)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **web browser on the iPhone** to upload the files to your server.
On the **server you can run your .NET** page that accepts those files.

To implement this:
**On the server**: create a ASP.NET Page to upload file as describe [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020140211/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/091201-1.shtml) or [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx).
**On the iPhone**: open the browser and type the URL of your page (of course deployed to your server) and upload the files required.

Comment: This is kind of what I had in mind. Do you know any resources or articles on that?

Comment: Added some resources to the answer.