# Error Undefined symbols: "_compress" with Image Upload Class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

im want use this Class [How can I upload a photo to a server with the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125306/how-can-i-upload-a-photo-to-a-server-with-the-iphone) to Upload an image from my iPhone App to my Webserver.

Ive Copyd the header and main file and added "#import "EPUploader.m"" to my ViewControler where i call the EPUploader Method.

Error Message is:

```
Ld build/Release-iphonesimulator/PhotoApp.app/PhotoApp normal i386
cd /Users/phil/PhotoApp
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.5
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk -L/Users/phil/PhotoApp/build/Release-iphonesimulator -F/Users/phil/PhotoApp/build/Release-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/phil/PhotoApp/build/NaoUp.build/Release-iphonesimulator/PhotoApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/PhotoApp.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/phil/PhotoApp/build/Release-iphonesimulator/PhotoApp.app/PhotoApp

Undefined symbols:
  "_compress", referenced from:
      -[EPUploader(Private) compress:] in EPUploader.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Sorry if its a noobie question.. im new to this :)

Answer (score 6):

You should add `libz.dylib` framework in your project.

Answer (score 1):

The question you link to shows this comment for the `compress:` method (edited for brevity):

```
* -[Uploader(Private) compress:] --
*      Uses zlib to compress the given data.
```

And inside the method, the call to `compress()`:

```
int error = compress([destData mutableBytes],
                     &destSize,
                     [data bytes],
                     [data length]);
```

It looks to me like you're not linking `zlib` with your application, so the linker can't figure out how to call `compress()`.  The [zlib homepage](http://www.zlib.net/) has everything you need to integrate the library with your app.

Also - it's a little weird to do `#import "EPUploader.m"`.  Normally you would only `#import` a header file.