# upload a file with progress bar in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how can I upload a file and display the completion on a progress bar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125306/how-can-i-upload-a-photo-to-a-server-with-the-iphone) for uploading files in general. Then hook its [`NSURLConnection`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)s `connection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:` together with a [`UIProgressView`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIProgressView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).