# iPhone: multi-part post using NSURLRequest

Tags: iphone

I've seen a few articles, forum posts talking about uploading a file using NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection.  Some of the ones I've seen are:

- http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=427513
- [How can I upload a photo to a server with the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125306/how-can-i-upload-a-photo-to-a-server-with-the-iphone)
- http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?HTTPFileUploadSample

However, most of them don't include any sort of variables along with the file.  Say I wanted to post the following variables (and their values) along with a photo:

```
user_id = 121
caption = this photo is awesome
thumbnail_x = 12
thumbnail_y = 0
thumbnail_w = 100
thumbnail_h = 200
photo = [file]
```

Is there a way to do this?

Or even better, is there already a class out there that builds on NSURLRequest that I could use?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One word

ASIHTTPFormRequest

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Comment: That doesn't actually answer the question.  Introducing a dependency to your application when cocoa can already handle should be done very discerningly.

Comment: the bit of the question "Or even better, is there already a class out there that builds on NSURLRequest that I could use?" hints that the OP may not mind a library, but I agree with you re use of external dependencies. However, ASIHTTP library is so useful I've long since swapped out my home grown lib for it.