# Upload image/Photo from Iphone to webserver(ASP.net)

Tags: asp.net, iphone

I am pretty new in Iphone Apps.
How do I upload Image/Photo from my Iphone to webserver. At web server I am using ASP.net c#.

On Iphone i have image displayed on UIImage Control and that image I am getting from database from BLOB datatype column.

how do I save that image bytes to application folder and then send image file to webserver.

Please help me with the Iphone as well as ASP.net code.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of examples on how to send a POST request with `NSURLConnection`. Likewise, there are plenty of examples of how to construct a Web Form that receives a posted file.

[This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125306/how-can-i-upload-a-photo-to-a-server-with-the-iphone) includes an example of posting a file, including zlib compression.

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/fileupload.aspx) will tell you how to deal with files on the ASP.NET side.