# How to upload a file from the front end (view) in an iphone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, file-upload, ios4

In my iphone app, It is a requirement that I enable the user to upload the database file  (.sql) from the front end of the app or through iTunes and the app should display the data based on the file he/she uploaded.

How should I go ahead with implementation?

Please give your suggestions.

Please Help.

Thanks!!

Comment: You'll need to provide more information as to what you have to work with on the server side, as that will make all the difference as to the solutions that can be recommended for your client side.

Comment: Hey jer, my client needs that he should be able to upload the database file so that his customers can get the updates that he wants to give them. So I am planning to provide a front end uploading for him so that he can upload the updated db file whenever he wants to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSURLConnection to FTP or HTTP POST the file. There is some server side programming required of course.

There are some answers in stackoverflow explaining the iphone upload like this:

[How can I upload a photo to a server with the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125306/how-can-i-upload-a-photo-to-a-server-with-the-iphone)

Comment: I am not exactly getting how to do this. I am a newbie. Can u please give some links for tutorials. Please Help. Thanks!!

Comment: What do you have server sided? How would you upload the file on a regular machine with a web browser?