# Image upload iphone to php server

Tags: iphone, http, post

i am using following code to upload image to php sever but IOException message is displayed can anybody help me in this?

```
- (void)uploadFileToURL:(NSURL *)url FileData:(NSData *)fileData FileParameterName:(NSString *)fileParameterName FileName:(NSString *)fileName withParameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
{
    NSMutableString *params = nil;
    NSURL *finalURL = url;
    if (parameters != nil)
    {
        params = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        for (id key in parameters)
        {
            NSString *encodedKey = [key stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            CFStringRef value = (CFStringRef)[[parameters objectForKey:key] copy];
            // Escape even the "reserved" characters for URLs 
            // as defined in http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt
            CFStringRef encodedValue = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, 
                                                                               value,
                                                                               NULL, 
                                                                               (CFStringRef)@";/?:@&=+$,", 
                                                                               kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
            [params appendFormat:@"%@=%@&", encodedKey, encodedValue];
            CFRelease(value);
            CFRelease(encodedValue);
        }
        [params deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([params length] - 1, 1)];
            NSString *urlWithParams = [[url absoluteString] stringByAppendingFormat:@"?%@", params];
            finalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlWithParams];
        }
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:finalURL
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:60.0];
    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
    NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];
    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", fileName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:fileData]];
    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setHTTPBody:postbody];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [self startConnection:request];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try posting to that URL from a web page launched in your simulator's browser? The code you have given seems to be right. I suspect the server connection.

You might also want to look at the thread:

[How can I upload a photo to a server with the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125306/how-can-i-upload-a-photo-to-a-server-with-the-iphone)