# iPhone taking a picture and posting it to a database

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, camera

I'm currently adding some photo-taking functionality to my application.

I'm curious about something, though. After the photo is taken, this code holds it as a piece of data:

`NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(saveImage);`

What I need to know is how the picture, after taken by the user, would get sent to the web via a PHP script. The script has been written, but on the iPhone end, what would I have to do programatically to ensure it gets sent to the database in the right format for viewing?  I have the "POST" NSURL request setup, which I've used many times for posting strings/numbers, but I don't know if this is different for photo data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Google, search for 'cocoa upload photo iphone', see first result:
[How can I upload a photo to a server with the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125306/how-can-i-upload-a-photo-to-a-server-with-the-iphone)