# Sample code for file upload resuming on iOS?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, file-upload

I have an iOS app where the user has the capability to upload video. I'd like to be able to support the resuming of uploads for when an upload is interrupted by the network, user, or any other circumstance. I realize this will require changes both on the client and server-side. I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction for sample code and/or documentation I can read for clues in how to support this functionality? Something with clues on proper chunking, figuring out what chunk was last sent after an interrupted connection, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#resuming_interrupted_downloads) for this. It is a great replacement library for anything network.

Answer (score 0):

See [ASIHTTPRequest documentation](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use)

Or

you can [download sample code here](http://www.sendspace.com/file/cnaeh1)

1 - [How can I upload a photo to a server with the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125306/how-can-i-upload-a-photo-to-a-server-with-the-iphone)