# IPhone: File Upload using dispatch_async for background upload

Tags: iphone, file, asynchronous, upload, background

I want to perform a image upload while the running application at the background. I am able to upload the image to the server using the code on this link. 
[How can I upload a photo to a server with the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125306/how-can-i-upload-a-photo-to-a-server-with-the-iphone)

I heard the NSUrlConnection can be asynchronous and it was used in the EPUploader. In my code, I add some extra method that will create a file in the application directory used for the EPUploader. During this creation of the file, I don't want it to create on the main thread of the application so I wrap all the code including the EPUploader itself with the 
dispatch_async on the global queue. That way I won't block the main thread while the file are creating.

It has no problem if I use dispatch_sync but dispatch_async I find something weird when I placed the breakpoint at NSUrlConnection connection :

```
- (void)upload
```

{

```
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    //ASSERT(data);
    if (!data) {
            [self uploadSucceeded:NO];
        return;
    }
    if ([data length] == 0) {
        // There's no data, treat this the same as no file.
        [self uploadSucceeded:YES];
        return;
    } /* blah blah */
    NSURLConnection * connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];

     if (!connection) {
        [self uploadSucceeded:NO];
        return;
    }
    else
        return;
```

I went to debug at the breakpoint and instead of going to if statement, the debugger jumps to the first return statement of this method. After that, the selectors I passed on to this class never gets called. This happen only on dispatch_async and it work on dispatch_sync on the global queue.

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];     

    self.uploadIndex = 0;
    ALAsset *asset = [self.assets objectAtIndex:0];

    [[FileUploader alloc] initWithAsset:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.3:4159/default.aspx"]
                                  asset:asset
                               delegate:self
                           doneSelector:@selector(onUploadDone:)
                          errorSelector:@selector(onUploadError:)];
    //[self singleUpload:self.uploadIndex];
    [pool release];


});
```

Comment: Sorry to added the block stuff that late....

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that should be changed.

1. Remove the `NSAutoreleasePool`, it is not needed.
2. Copy the block to the heap because it's life will probably exceed that of the calling code.

Example:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0);

    dispatch_async(queue, [[^{
        self.uploadIndex = 0;
        ALAsset *asset = [self.assets objectAtIndex:0];

        [[FileUploader alloc] initWithAsset:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.3:4159/default.aspx"]
                                      asset:asset
                                   delegate:self
                               doneSelector:@selector(onUploadDone:)
                              errorSelector:@selector(onUploadError:)];
    } copy] autorelease]);
```

If you are using ARC (which you certainly are since you should be) there is no need for the `copy` or `autorelease`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ... I have tried but it gave the same result when I put breakpoint.