# Upload photo from iPhone to 4D Server

Tags: ios, web-services, 4d-database

I am looking to upload a photo from iPhone to a 4D Server. Specifically to upload a photo taken on an iPhone, uploaded to a 4D Server and stored as a JPEG image in the WebFolder. I am using 4D Server version 12 and 13. I have looked at other postings here but I cannot make any of them apply to 4D. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Is your problem with the iOS side or the 4D side?

Comment: Using a 4DACTION method the problem would be on the 4D side on how to receive the data sent by the iPhone using something like NSURL. I am sure there are other ways but I do not know of them at present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a while but I finally puzzled together the various procedures to make this work. Thumbs up to the iriphon blog (http://www.iriphon.com/2011/11/09/ios-uploading-an-image-from-your-iphone-to-a-server/) for putting me on the right track.

Here is the iOS code I used:

```
-(IBAction)uploadPhoto:(id)sender {
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/4DACTION/showcaseUploadPic"]
                                                            cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                        timeoutInterval:60]; 

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 

// We need to add a header field named Content-Type with a value that tells that it's a form and also add a boundary.
// I just picked a boundary by using one from a previous trace, you can just copy/paste from the traces.
NSString *boundary = @"----WebKitFormBoundaryQkZe6RUJZ2xbzXLB";

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];

[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
// end of what we've added to the header.

// the body of the post.
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

// Now we need to append the different data 'segments'. We first start by adding the boundary.
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// Now append the image
// Note that the name of the form field is exactly the same as in the trace ('picBLOB' in my case).
// You can choose whatever filename you want.
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"picBLOB\" filename=\"image001.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// We now need to tell the receiver what content type we have.
// In my case it's a jpg image. If you have a png, set it to 'image/png'.
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: image/jpg\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// Now we append the actual image data.
// I use a NSData object called photoData.
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:photoData]];

NSLog(@"photoData size = %i",[photoData length]);

// and again the delimiting boundary.
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// adding the body we've created to the request.
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSURLConnection * connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
NSLog(@"connection = %@",connection);
}
```

Don't forget to include the NSURLConnection delegates!

I used Wireshark, as described in the blog, to get the exact data I needed. I am using NSData to store the photo I had just taken with the camera and want to upload. Because of this my code is slightly different than if you wanted to upload a stored file.

Here is the 4D (version 12) code:

```
$ba:=BLOB size(picBLOB)
C_PICTURE(imageVar)
If (Undefined(picBLOB))  // in case user tries to reload /4DACTION/WEB_Set_Limits
C_BLOB(picBLOB)
End if 

If (BLOB size(picBLOB)>0)  // did user select a file for uploading?
C_STRING(255;$fileHeader)
$offset:=0  // BLOB to text requires a variable for the offset parameter
$fileHeader:=BLOB to text(picBLOB;Mac text without length;$offset;255)
$fileNameBegin:=Position("filename=";$fileHeader)+10
For ($i;$fileNameBegin;255)
If ($fileHeader≤$i≥=Char(Double quote))
$fileNameEnd:=$i
$i:=255
End if 
End for 
$fileName:=Substring($fileHeader;$fileNameBegin;$fileNameEnd-$fileNameBegin)
$contentTypeBegin:=Position("Content-Type:";$fileHeader)+14
For ($i;$contentTypeBegin;255)
If ($fileHeader≤$i≥=Char(Carriage return))
$contentTypeEnd:=$i
$i:=255
End if 
End for 
contentType:=Substring($fileHeader;$contentTypeBegin;$contentTypeEnd-$contentTypeBegin)
DELETE FROM BLOB(picBLOB;0;$contentTypeEnd+3)

BLOB TO PICTURE(picBLOB;imageVar;"JPEG")
$FILENAME:=":WebFolder:myPhoto.jpg"
WRITE PICTURE FILE($FILENAME;imageVar;"JPEG")

End if
```

Here is the 4D (version 13) code:

```
C_BLOB(picBLOB)
C_PICTURE(imageVar)

WEB GET BODY PART(1;picBLOB;myPhoto)

If (BLOB size(picBLOB)>0)
BLOB TO PICTURE(picBLOB;imageVar;"JPEG")
$FILENAME:=":WebFolder:myPhoto.jpg"
WRITE PICTURE FILE($FILENAME;imageVar;"JPEG")
End if
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not particularly familiar with this "4D Server" but sounds like you would just need a simple server side PHP script to upload the photo, probably using NSData.

What exactly have you tried, or what is the extent of your knowledge in both of these areas?

Comment: I tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125306/how-can-i-upload-a-photo-to-a-server-with-the-iphone and I am trying not to use ASIHttpRequest as it is no longer being supported. PHP is not native in 4D and I am not well versed in PHP myself. FYI 4D is at www.4d.com

Answer (score 1):

This [page](http://www.4dresources.com/codefaq/uploads1.shtml) has instructions for working with an earlier version. A [more recent post](http://4d.1045681.n5.nabble.com/Uploading-files-in-v12-td4686550.html) on the iNug (4D's dev mailing list) suggests that this still works, perhaps with a few tweeks.

You'll get a better response asking on the [iNug](https://lists.4d.com/mailman/listinfo/4d_tech) simply because the 4D community is so small.