# File Upload issue in ipad

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, css

I am using  http://uniformjs.com/ for form elements its work fine in all browser as well as different devices, but only a thing which I noticed is about “File Upload” function is not work in iPad.

Anyone can guide how to fix this issue, without download any other supported app like picupapp.com

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In iOS (iPhone and iPad), file upload through browser *just doesn't work*.

You'll need to create an *App for that*. See some info about file upload Cocoa here: [How can I upload a photo to a server with the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125306/how-can-i-upload-a-photo-to-a-server-with-the-iphone)

Or, if you can afford to leave out all the pre iOS6 devices, it seems like they added support for `<input type="file">` in their latest version.

Comment: iOS 6 added support for `<input type="file">`, so that is no longer true.